# Por que a função pickrandom não funciona e como substui-lo?

Tags: javascript, array, google, arraylist, random

Comecei a aprender **JavaScript** pelo aplicativo do *Google* **Grasshopper**, que diz ensinar códigos do **Javascript**.

O problema é que no aplicativo aprendi a usar a função *pickRandom* para selecionar aleatoriamente uma escolha dentro de uma *array*, mas aparentemente essa função não funciona de verdade em lugar **nenhum!**

No aplicativo eu testei o seguinte código que funcionou, mas não consegui fazer ele funcionar em mais nenhum lugar:

```js
var marbe = pickRandom(['cup1', 'cup2', 'cup3',]);
if (marbe!=='cup2') {console.log(pickRandom(['oops,try again', 'not your lucky day', 'maybe next time',]));} 
else {console.log(pickRandom(['GOTCHA!', 'YOU HIT THE JACKPOT!', 'LOOK WHAT U FOUND!',]));}
```

Gostaria de saber como utilizar o código real desta função (aquele que de fato existe no JavaScript, e não o utilizado no aplicativo)

Comment: Na verdade não, não é para ensinar os códigos mais usados, funções como pickRandom, drawBox, drawBoxes, são funções customizadas, ou seja, **NÃO são nativas**, servem apenas para **ILUSTRAR** resultados, para que de forma mais "visual" você entenda o comportamento básico da linguagem, não tem haver com códigos especificos, o principio é ajudar a entender o comportamento de parametros, argumentos, funções e etc, de qualquer tipo.

Answer (score 1):

Se procurar no suporte da plataforma Grasshopper sobre a função `pickRandom()` encontrará o documento [Funções personalizadas do Grasshopper](https://support.grasshopper.app/t/grasshopper-custom-functions/2296) cujo o texto informa:

> **`pickRandom()`**
> *Definição*: Esta função pega arrays ou números, ou variáveis ​​contendo números ou arrays, e seleciona um elemento aleatório.
> `pickRandom()` não faz muito por conta própria, mas pode ser útil
> quando combinado com outras funções.
>
> *Como replicar fora do Grasshopper*: Uma definição de função para `pickRandom()` poderia ser semelhante à mostrada abaixo.
>
> ```
> /**
> * Recebe um parâmetro e seleciona um elemento aleatório.
> * @param {number | array} argument - pode ser passado um número ou
> * array. Se for passado um número essa função retorna um inteiro
> * aleatório no intervalo [0,argument].
> * Se for passado um array, a função retorna um dos elementos do 
> * array.
> * @return {number | Object} - O tipo do valor retornado depende do 
> * tipo de objeto passado em argument.
> */
> function pickRandom(argument) {
>   //Se o tipo do parâmetro argument for number...   
>   if (typeof argument === 'number') {
>     //... retorna um inteiro aleatório no intervalo [0,argument].
>     return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(argument)) + 1;
>   }
>   //Se o tipo do parâmetro argument for Array...
>   if (Array.isArray(argument)) {
>     //... retorna aleatoriamente um dos elementos do array.
>     return argument[Math.floor(Math.random() * argument.length)];
>   }
> }
> ```

Então aplicando essa informação em seu código:

```js
function pickRandom(argument) {
  if (typeof argument === 'number') {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(argument)) + 1;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(argument)) {
    return argument[Math.floor(Math.random() * argument.length)];
  }
}

var marbe = pickRandom(['cup1', 'cup2', 'cup3', ]);
if (marbe !== 'cup2') {
  console.log(pickRandom(['oops,try again', 'not your lucky day', 'maybe next time', ]));
} else {
  console.log(pickRandom(['GOTCHA!', 'YOU HIT THE JACKPOT!', 'LOOK WHAT U FOUND!', ]));
}
```

Referência:
[MDN Web Docs - Declaração de função(function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)
[MDN Web Docs - Operador typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
[MDN Web Docs - Função Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)
[MDN Web Docs - Função Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
[MDN Web Docs - Método Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
[MDN Web Docs - Declaração if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
[MDN Web Docs - Declaração return](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Ainda não entendi como aplicar essa substituição, já que ela é maior do que aquela aprendida anteriormente por mim. Não vou conseguir simplesmente substituir sem entender como funciona. Gostaria de uma explicação melhor, por favor.

Comment: Essa função `pickRandom()` ela não existe. É uma invenção dos criadores dos Grasshopper para poderem usar exercícios sobre escolhas aleatórias na plataforma. Esse é código que usam só que não mostram para a principio evitar ruído. O que você quer saber, o que faz cada linha?

Comment: @AugustoVasques entendo sua boa vontade em ajudar, os links são bons, mas após a seguinte postagem do AP ficou um pouco mais claro que o problema não é reproduzir o "código fora" do Grasshopper, mas sim que o entendimento do AP esta equivocado, acreditando que isso são os códigos mais usados javascript, quando na verdade são apenas para uso de aprendizado, como eu [comentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/535741/por-que-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pickrandom-n%c3%a3o-funciona-e-como-substui-lo#comment965443_535741).

Comment: Estou fechando a pergunta porque não é bem o que o autor precisa e não esta dentro dos "conformes" da maneira que ela foi elaborada. Ainda sim o AP pode [edit] a qualquer momento e revisar essa situação.

Comment: Creio que no caso você se equivocou quanto a interpretação do meu pedido. Sim, eu queria saber como reproduzir o real código fora do aplicativo, só que não havia entendido sem a explicação linha por linha. (Aliás, eu sei que a função citada no post é um código elaborado para aprendizagem)